# Statically compiling python program to be able to run in an empty container

Tags: python, docker, static-linking

I have a program `my_prog.py` written in python.
I want to statically compile it into a standalone binary that can run inside an arbitrary or empty container:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
```

My goal is that I just mount a volume containing the compiled program and the program runs successfully:

```sh
docker run --volume=~/programs:/programs /programs/my_prog
```

How can I accomplish this?
I've read about python freeze and pyInstaller, but I'm not sure they produce standalone binaries.

P.S. A "standalone" directory of files is probably fine too. As long as it can work when mounted to a non-root directory inside the container.

Comment: Are the alpine images too large for what you want to accomplish?  Seems like an easier solution: https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/21d2ab0a50100ebdaf32f4bbb214bf21f857d1da/3.8/alpine3.11/Dockerfile

Comment: I have a different goal - running a go program inside an *arbitrary* user-provided image. It's likely does not have python at all. It might not even have package manager.

Comment: "I've read about python freeze and pyInstaller, but I'm not sure they produce standalone binaries." They do not. Look into Cython, although even that depends on the CPython runtime/libraries, I'm pretty sure. I don't really see a way around distributing it with at least that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga A "standalone" directory of files is probably fine too. As long as it can work when mounted to a non-root directory inside the container.

Comment: Yes, I bet someone has solved this with CYthon. there is no standard tool for this though, so good luck.